# How to download a csv using pyppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, pyppeteer

I am new to pyppeteer and try to download a csv. Unfortunately, without success. Suppose I want to download the following csv: 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv'. Simply using

```
await self.page.goto('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv')
```

does not help. I tried to use

```
cdp = await self.page.target.createCDPSession()
await cdp.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { 'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': '/test'})
```

but it's also not working. If someone knows how to make it work or can give me any advice, I'd highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss the `_client` module of the page object. I am not that expert in python, but it seems that will do the job without `createCDPSession()`, also the path is suspicious that it is not recognized, try an absolute one as `downloadPath`.

```py
await self.page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { 'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': 'C:/test' })
await self.page.goto('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I don't get an error but it doesn't trigger a download either.

Comment: I see. **You might need an absolute path as `downloadPath`, perhaps the relative path is expected in different format and that causes a silent error.** I modify my answer like that. Other than that: does other part of your code works as expected? What if you leave out `self.` in general from your code?

Comment: Has changing the path solved the issue in the meantime?